# Spring File Upload Internal server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using spring mvc. My form:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Name: <input type="text" name=name><br> 
       Email ID: <input type="email" name=emailID><br> 
       Attachment: <input type="file" name=file id="file"><br> 
       Submit?: <input type="submit" name=submit value="Done"><br>
    </form>
```

I get an internal server error.

The error is:

1)505 Error

2)No Stack Trace

The form resets itself rather than go to the next page which is a notice page.

Comment: Can you show the exception stack trace?

Comment: What's the actual error?  "Internal server error" means something failed in server-side code.  What failed?

Comment: THat's the thing, there is no stack trace. It says internal server error 505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe you should always use POST or PUT when doing uploads else you are going to [lose characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) along the way as only ASCII is supported then.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Make sure that you have [Spring configured correctly](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) for file uploads, meaning that you have setup a `MultipartResolver`, without it Spring is not going to support file uploads.

Your controller should use data-binding, instead of doing it yourself (use the framework).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", params = "submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addForm(@ModelAttribute PostModel newPost){
    System.out.println("Added " + newPost.getQuestion() + " successfully");
    System.out.println("Added the file " + file.getName() + "successfully");
    return addController.showNotice(newPost.getQuestion());
}
```