# AngularJS file upload displays 500 Internal server error when file is above 500KB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have a basic AngularJS code to send a file to my REST controller.
When I upload a text file which is around 500 KB then it is working fine. When the size exceeds 600 KB then I get "500 Internal server error" and the request is not reaching the REST controller of back-end application

I heard that changing the header will resolve this issue. Could someone please help?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="uploadFile(this.files)"/>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);
    var uploadUrl = ApiUrlFull + 'Job/Item?smartTermId=0&name=aaa1&quantity=1&ApiKey=ABC';
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success( ...all right!... ).error( ..damn!... );

};
```

Comment: Internal server error would mean that it is an issue with the server though, not with the client.

Comment: Check the server configurations. The server is configured to now allow files above specific size.

Comment: @NaveedKamran You are right. I see that the back end is configured to allow only a max size of 500 kb. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in Back end REST application

The CommonsMultipartResolver has the max size set as 0.5 MB
Increase the size to whatever is required.

Please refer,
[Spring File Upload Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831108/spring-file-upload-internal-server-error)